# Creating a String from a Collection of Objects

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a question. I have a class of `Cars` that I need to display in a simpli-ish string if they will be sold or not base on their number.

So like this:

```
Public Class Car
    Property Index As Integer
    Property Sell As Boolean
End Class
Public Class Cars
    Property Vehicles As New List(Of Car) From {
                    {New Car With {.Index = 1, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 2, .Sell = False}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 3, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 4, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 5, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 6, .Sell = False}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 7, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 8, .Sell = True}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 9, .Sell = False}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 10, .Sell = False}},
                    {New Car With {.Index = 11, .Sell = True}}}
End Class
```

I'd like to display a simple string like this:
**Cars to be sold: 1, 3-5, 7-8, 11**, which is based of the `.Sell` value.

Is there some kind of heuristic to create this kind of string in .NET or is it just a bunch of for/each and if/then and redimming of arrays?

Comment: Linq would definitely be more concise than For Each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ would definitely simplify the solution. Without LINQ you could use a `StringBuilder` and iterate over the list while comparing neighboring items and build up the string. That would be more ideal rather than redimming arrays and such.

Here's a LINQ solution:

```
Dim query = vehicles.Where(Function(c) c.Sell) _
                    .OrderBy(Function(c) c.Index) _
                    .Select(Function(c, i) New With { .Car = c, .Diff = c.Index - vehicles(i).Index }) _
                    .GroupBy(Function(item) item.Diff) _
                    .Select(Function(item) item.First().Car.Index.ToString() &
                        If(item.Count() > 1, "-" & item.Last().Car.Index.ToString(), ""))

Console.WriteLine("Cars to be sold: " & String.Join(", ", query.ToArray()))
```

With .NET 4 you can drop the `ToArray()` call since `String.Join` has an overload that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The code filters out cars with a `Sell` value of `True`. It is important for the list to be in order of `Car.Index` for this to work properly, hence the `OrderBy`. The logic behind determining consecutive items is to compare neighboring items and group them based on their index difference. If there's a difference of 1 then they are neighbors. So the second `Select` projects into an anonymous type that stores the `Car` and the `Diff` based on the current index minus the previous car's index. The `GroupBy` groups all the differences together. The last `Select` builds the range. If the `Count` is greater than 1 we put a dash between the first and last group items. Otherwise one item exists and we select it as it is. Finally we use `String.Join` to return the list of values separated by commas.

Comment: I'm impressed, this is really clean and concise. Linq is definetely the way to go. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
Dim list_sold = Vehicles.Where(Function(x As Car) x.Sell = True)
Dim list_index = list_sold.Select(Function(x As Car) x.Index.ToString())

Console.WriteLine("Cars to be sold: {0}", String.Join(", ", list_index))
```

Comment: This gives a comma separated output but doesn't group the neighboring indices together.

Comment: I see that now. I did not notice originally the 3-5 grouping.